# Setting an interval on a click event in React using Hooks won't use updated state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, setinterval

I am trying to create a filter dropdown menu that hides itself if the user did not close it manually and has moved their mouse away from the filter after 1 second.

The problem is that the `mouseInside` boolean state never gets changed to `false` inside the interval. I believe this is because the react component gets re-rendered but not entirely sure.

I don't know how to fix it or how I might be using state vs local variables incorrectly.

I'm using TypeScript in React with hooks:

```
const Filter: React.FC = () => {
  const [shown, setShown] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [mouseInside, setMouseInside] = useState<boolean>(false);
  
  let interval: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  const handleToggle = () => {
      setShown(!shown);
      
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(mouseInside);

        // mouseInside is permanently true
        if (!mouseInside && interval) {
           // this never gets triggered
           clearInterval(interval);
           setShown(false);
           console.log("Finished!");
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}  
      onClick={handleToggle}
      onMouseEnter={() => setMouseInside(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setMouseInside(false)}
    >
        <p>Click me!</p>
        
        {shown && <div>drop down here...</dv>}
    </div>
    );
};
```

I need mouseInside to eventually change to false when the user leaves the filter box. The `onMouseLeave` event is definitely being triggered but it's the React side of things I think is causing the issue.

Maybe I need to use `useEffect`? I don't know the best approach though on how to use this with `setInterval`.

Comment: Where do you use `handleToggle`?

Comment: @GalAbra sorry. I forgot to include it in the sample. Just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using part of what @GalAbra suggested but I wanted to only create the interval when the user clicks on the toggler and only if the menu was open:

```
  const [shown, setShown] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [mouseInside, setMouseInside] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval: NodeJS.Timeout | null;

    if (shown) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!mouseInside && interval) {
          setShown(false);
        }
      }, 500);
    }

    return () => {
      if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [shown, mouseInside]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}  
      onClick={() => setShown(!shown)}
      onMouseEnter={() => setMouseInside(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setMouseInside(false)}
    >
        <p>Click me!</p>        
        {shown && <div>drop down here...</dv>}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to "subscribe" a callback function to a change in state, you can definitely use the `useEffect` hook:

```js
function automaticallySetMouseOutside() {  
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (mouseInside) {
      setMouseInside(false);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

useEffect(automaticallySetMouseOutside, [mouseInside]);
```

`useEffect`'s second argument subscribes `automaticallySetMouseOutside` to get called whenever `mouseInside` is changed.

While this code is meant to exemplify the use of this hook, **it's not accurate** - as it can close the menu while the user is still inside.
If you want a full solution to your issue, please check this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/galabra-useeffect-example-m1gjo?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. I had to useEffect like you suggested and was able to create the interval only when the user clicks the drop down. I had to edit it slightly though.

Comment: Good to hear! Usually it's preferable [not to use `setInterval`](https://chrisblackwell.me/setinterval-is-bad/), as it can cause performance issues

Comment: yes this was my main concern. Most examples I found online relied on the interval always running but I only wanted it to run if the menu was open to avoid performance issues. I posted my updated version because it did differ a lot from your example but you put me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

While declaring the interval action inside `handleToggle`, it lives inside its own scope, with no binding to the actual state,

```
const handleInterval = interval => { 
        console.log(mouseInside);
        if (!mouseInside && interval) {
           // this never gets triggered
           clearInterval(interval);
           setShown(false);
           console.log("Finished!");
        }
      }
   
const handleToggle = () => {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        () => handleInterval(interval),
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using useEffect to ensure I had the same reference to the interval.

Comment: be aware that cause you declare `let interval` inside the effect, each time you enter the effect you declare new `interval`...

consider use `let interval = useRef(null)` outside the effect, and assign or clear `interval.current` instead

Comment: Thank you. I updated my solution. I thought using `interval.current = setInterval` would still mean I am creating a new interval each time I enter the effect?

Comment: I had to edit the answer back without useRef because that was causing issues with multiple tabs opened with the component rendered on each tab. Very odd.